# Call new data frame for each iteration: Loop through data frames?

Tags: r, loops, recursion, iteration, simulation

I am designing a simulation that iteratively runs a block of code using inputs from two separate data frames (`df` and `year`). The resulting data frame is a modified version of `df`, which is then saved on my hard-drive under two separate file names: one that is permanently stored for future analysis, and another that is recalled for the next iteration.

Here is my problem: The data frame `year` needs to be a completely new data frame for each iteration (i.e., the following year's data).

Could this be accomplished with something like a for loop, where the index `[i]` is the next year's data frame (rather than a row within a data frame, which is how I understand for loops to operate)? I suspect the answer involves a list? Here are some dummy data attempting to demonstrate the issue:

```
df <- tibble(
  x = 1:25,
  y = rnorm(25, 22, 8))

year1990 <- tibble(
  Year = 1990, 
  DayOfYear = 1:6, 
  temp = seq(0, 20, 4))

year1991 <- tibble(
  Year = 1991, 
  DayOfYear = 1:6, 
  temp = seq(0, 25, 5))

year1992 <- tibble(
  Year = 1992, 
  DayOfYear = 1:6, 
  temp = seq(0, 15, 3))

#### Beginning of Code to Be Repeated ####

year <- year1990         # Start with this year, BUT each subsequent iteration needs the following year's data
df$survive <- ifelse(max(year$temp) <= df$y, "Dead", "Live")
write.csv(df, "location/f.csv",row.names=FALSE)  # Write temporary CSV to be recalled
write.csv(df, paste(year[1,1], ".csv", sep = ""), row.names = FALSE)      # Write permanent CSV for storage

#### End of Code to Be Repeated ####

# Reload the newly modified data frame
setwd()
df <- read.csv("df.csv")
```

Currently, I manually reload `df` and reset the `year` for each iteration (e.g., I would reassign `year` using `year1991` for the second iteration in this example), but I'm certain there's a better way to automate the entire process. Thank you!

Comment: Where do you *reset the year for each iteration*? I'm confused as there is no *year* in df.

Comment: @Parfait, Thanks for the question. The line just after "Beginning...", I assign the object name `year` using the next year's data. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply save objects in a named list (which can be created if they originally were in one data frame with `split` or `by`). Then loop elementwise with `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) through list's names and objects through a defined process for looping

```
year_list <- list(
  year1990 = tibble(Year = 1990, DayOfYear = 1:6, temp = seq(0, 20, 4)),    
  year1991 = tibble(Year = 1991, DayOfYear = 1:6, temp = seq(0, 25, 5)),    
  year1992 = tibble(Year = 1992, DayOfYear = 1:6, temp = seq(0, 15, 3))
)

proc <- function(n, d) {    
    year <- d        
    df$survive <- ifelse(max(year$temp) <= df$y, "Dead", "Live")
    write.csv(df, "location/f.csv", row.names = FALSE)  

    # Write temporary CSV to be recalled
    write.csv(df, paste0(n, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)  

    return(df)
}

# ITERATIVELY SAVES CSVs AND RETURNS dfs WITH UPDATED survive COLUMN
output_list <- Map(proc, names(year_list), year_list)
```

Comment: This certainly works, thank you! By using  _**do.call("rbind", output_list)_** I combined the list into a single data frame. Two small issues: #1: I'm still a little fuzzy on what `n` is doing in the second _**write.csv**_ function. I need to study up on `mapply` perhaps. #2: How can I create a new column in `df` that stores the year for that iteration?

Comment: Indeed you can row bind all at the end. And *n* is being passed into the file name of `write.csv`. It is iterated elementwise with *d*. Simply add a line for column before the `write.csv` calls: `df$year <- n`.